# Cross Origin with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cors, kineticjs

I have images hosted on a server, and the KineticJS app running on another server.

**Problem:** When attempting `stage.toDataURL()`, I get the CORS error:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

[image]

I have adjusted Apache to allow CORS

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE"
```

When the image is CURLed, I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2013 21:29:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Jan 2013 21:27:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 166812
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

However the `SECURITY_ERR` error still occurs!

Is there another step necessary to perform `.toDataURL()` with images from another domain, maybe using a cross-origin tag?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error? If you are using Chrome it will print out a more detailed explanation of why it failed.

Comment: In Chrome, I get the error message `Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 `. Added a screenshot to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [at this issue](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/151).

> (eduardo-martos) Are you trying to generate a dataUrl from a canvas with an image from a different domain? If that's your case, then there is nothing you can do on the front-end. A proxy on your back-end may be the solution.

Quote from [the linked tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/):

> Note: The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I am wondering how will the proxy (like Squid?) knows which domain the image is at in the case where our images can be at locations `farm1.domain.com`, `farm2.domain.com` etc